# Проблемма при подключении php файла к базе данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Даже не знаю как объяснить, потому что относительно недолго работаю с PHP & MySQL.
Получается создал php-файл в котором содержится вот этот код

```
<?php
mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '')
OR die( 'Could not connect to database.');
mysql_select_db('hfjq_race_info');
echo "Connected!";
?>
```

Когда хочу запустить этот файл выдаёт такие 3 ошибки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: mysql поднят на локальной машине? запущен?

Comment: @sterx Привет, да запущен. Запускал его на Apache

Comment: 1) В ошибке фигурирует `SHA2 Auth`. Проверьте настройки авторизации. 2) Пустой пароль обычно запрещен для удаленного доступа. Введите хоть к-то пароль рут-у

Comment: @DNS Хотелбы спросить, а MySQL сервер должен быть установлен в одной папке с сервером или это не имеет значения?

Comment: Не имеет значения

Comment: @DNS Не всеравно что-то не работает, получается я создавал базу данных через MySQL Workbanch с помощью этого кода `create database hfjq_race_info;
CREATE USER 'runner_db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'runner_db_password';
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON hfjq_race_info.* TO 'runner_db_user'@'localhost';
use hfjq_race_info;
CREATE TABLE runners(
runner_id INT not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(100) not null,
last_name VARCHAR(100) not null,
gender VARCHAR(1) not null,
finish_time VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (runner_id)
);` может я в нём накосячил((

Comment: Да так ошибок не видно... Попробуйте подключаться при помощи [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)